# Highlighting links based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the my links to highlight if the user is scrolling over the page that is for that link. But for some reason it isn't working properly. I Have commented out my first try in jquery and tried again but link two is highlighting when link one should.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" id="link_1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
   <p></p>
</nav>

<div id="sec_one" class="sections">

</div>

<div id="sec_two" class="sections">

</div>

<div id="sec_three" class="sections">

</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li a{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a{

}

.sections{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#sec_one{
  background-color: blue;
}

#sec_two{
  background-color: red;
}

#sec_three{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active{
  background-color: #666666;
}

p{
  color: white;
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var page1Top = $("#sec_one").scrollTop();
  var page1Bot = $("#sec_one").outerHeight();

  var page2Top = $("#sec_two").scrollTop();
  var page2Bot = $("#sec_two").outerHeight();

  var page3Top = $("#sec_three").scrollTop();
  var page3Bot = $("#sec_three").outerHeight();

 /*if(scrollPos >= page1Top && scrollPos < page1Bot){
    $("#link_1").addClass("active");
    $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
    $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
  }else if(scrollPos >= page2Top && scrollPos < page2Bot){
    $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
    $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
    $("#link_2").addClass("active");
  }else if(scrollPos >= page3Top && scrollPos < page3Bot){
    $("#link_3").addClass("active");
    $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
    $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
  }*/

  if(scrollPos >= page1Top && scrollPos < page1Bot){
    $("#link_1").addClass("active");
    $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
    $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
    }else {
      $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
    }

  if(scrollPos >= page2Top && scrollPos < page2Bot){
    $("#link_2").addClass("active");
    $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
    $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
    }else {
      $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is you're not using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) - With your code you're just getting the position relative to itself so the top always becomes `0` and bottom becomes `2000` - using `offset` would mean you're getting the position relative to the document so that it takes into account other elements as well.

Also you don't need to check the bottom location. You can just use the top location of the next section.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    var page1Top = $("#sec_one").offset().top;
    var page2Top = $("#sec_two").offset().top;
    var page3Top = $("#sec_three").offset().top;

    if (scrollPos >= page1Top && scrollPos < page2Top) {
      $("#link_1").addClass("active");
      $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
    }

    if (scrollPos >= page2Top && scrollPos < page3Top) {
      $("#link_2").addClass("active");
      $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
    }
    
    if (scrollPos >= page3Top) {
      $("#link_3").addClass("active");
      $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a {}

.sections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#sec_one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#sec_two {
  background-color: red;
}

#sec_three {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
  background-color: #666666;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" id="link_1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p></p>
</nav>

<div id="sec_one" class="sections"></div>
<div id="sec_two" class="sections"></div>
<div id="sec_three" class="sections"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the target of individual elements and the use of the rough ID's, you can evaluate the `scrollTop` and the `offset().top` of the element and based on the index of the section highlight the item you need:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
      navH     = $('nav').height();
  $('.sections').each(function(i){
    var offT = $(this).offset().top;
    if((offT-scrollPos-navH) <= 0) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active')
      $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active')
    }
  })
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;} nav { width: 100%; background-color: black; position: fixed; top: 0;} nav ul { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; list-style-type: none; text-align: center;} nav ul li { display: inline; width: 100%;} nav ul li a { font-size: 40px; color: white; text-decoration: none;} .sections { width: 100%; height: 2000px;} #sec_one { background-color: blue;} #sec_two { background-color: red;} #sec_three { background-color: yellow;} .active { background-color: #666666;} p { color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" id="link_1" class="active">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p></p>
</nav>
<div id="sec_one" class="sections"></div>
<div id="sec_two" class="sections"></div>
<div id="sec_three" class="sections"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote this a bit so you aren't calculating each individual element in your JS and you can just find which div you've scrolled into dynamically and modify the class of the matching nav element.

```js
var $sections = $('.sections'),
    $lis = $('nav li');

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
      navHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();
  $sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
    if (scrollPos > top - navHeight && scrollPos < bottom) {
      var $target = $lis.eq($(this).index() - 1);
      $lis.not($target).removeClass('active');
      $target.addClass('active');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sections{
  height: 200vh;;
}

#sec_one{
  background-color: blue;
}

#sec_two{
  background-color: red;
}

#sec_three{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active{
  background-color: #666666;
}

p{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" id="link_1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p></p>
</nav>

<div id="sec_one" class="sections">

</div>

<div id="sec_two" class="sections">

</div>

<div id="sec_three" class="sections">

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: More downvotes! I would love to hear some feedback if my answer is doesn't help OP.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming you want the links to link to different divs on the page and not a completely different page.

You can use [ScrollSpy](https://plugins.jquery.com/scrollSpy/) to accomplish this really easily. The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy).

Here's some sample code for how you would do this on your page:

First, reference the `scrollspy.js` file. Be sure to use the relative url depending on where you choose to save the file.

`<script src="scrollspy.js"></script>`

Then, in your page script file, you could have something like this.

```
$('.sections').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
  switch($(this).attr('id')) {
    case "sec_one":
      $("#link_1").addClass("active");
      $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
      break;
    case "sec_two":
      $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_2").addClass("active");
      $("#link_3").removeClass("active");
      break;
    case "sec_three":
      $("#link_1").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_2").removeClass("active");
      $("#link_3").addClass("active");
      break;
  }
}

$('.sections').scrollSpy();
```